# Why can't Kotlin smart cast between an interface and the generic type that is derived from it?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-generics

I have the following class:

```
abstract class PresenterActivity<S : ViewState, I : ViewIntent> : AppCompatActivity() { 
    open fun initViewIntent(): I {
        return object : ViewIntent{} // type mismatch on this line
    }
}
```

I receive a pre-compilation error stating:

```
Type mismatch
Required: I
Found: <S, I>
```

To fix this pre-compilation error I am casting the ViewIntent object to I:

```
abstract class PresenterActivity<S : ViewState, I : ViewIntent> : AppCompatActivity() { 
    open fun initViewIntent(): I {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return object : ViewIntent{} as I
    }
}
```

But why can't Kotlin detect that `I` must be derived from `ViewIntent` and smart cast it?

Comment: `I` being derived from `ViewIntent` isn't _enough_ to make that a valid cast.  In fact, `ViewIntent` has to be derived from `I` to make the thing you're describing work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just because "I" is NOT necessarily derived from ViewIntent, but exactly ViewIntent class.

You can fix it like this:

```
abstract class PresenterActivity<S : ViewState, I : ViewIntent> : AppCompatActivity() { 
    open fun initViewIntent(): ViewIntent {
        return object : ViewIntent{} 
    }
}
```

Doing it your way is really unsafe.

To understand why, I guess you should start reading this:

https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-generics-variance-modifiers-36b82c7caa39

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47

Answer (score 8):

That's because `ViewIntent` isn't `I`. See example:

```
class MyViewIntent : ViewIntent

class MyPresenterActivity : PresenterActivity<..., MyViewIntent>() {
    // inherited from PresenterActivity
    open fun initViewIntent(): ViewIntent {
        return object : ViewIntent{} as MyViewIntent // you see where this breaks
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the reason why what you're doing doesn't work is because whatever `I` is is a subclass of `ViewIntent`. Your object is also a subclass `ViewIntent`. It's a completely different subclass. The cast you're doing is like trying to cast `StringBuilder` into a `String`.

Now let's discuss what I think you "want" to do and why that doesn't work either. In order to really get the result you want, you need to create the `I` type directly, like this:

```
return object : I {}
```

And in we replaced that `I` with an actual class,

```
return object : SomeClass {}
```

this would certainly fail, too. `SomeClass`'s constructor needs to be called, and you're not doing it. And there's no way to know what to pass into that constructor when using the generic type.